# why `[true, false] extends [false, false]` in typescript, sometimes it's right, and sometime it's not?

Tags: typescript

why below code return `["Why?", [true, false]]`?
[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMCGsDOB1ASxgAsAeNOUGYAOwBMc4cYoCaBzAGnWGwGNiGVh0ohq9Rs2HsAfHAC86UeIZwABgBIA3ml5QBQtuwC%202tgDNgUOABVjauAH4EUAK6oAXHHOYANjmAAbgAoUEhYBGRUAEkcADlgdkwYAgA3YFI45VpVGlcAWwAjKzlFDGwYfCIyTS04%2024AcgBaRpkQ0PBoeCQUdFdC0gBBbIk4PKKrbgAhUdyC4qhSuABtWISklPThmW51xOS0jOmZAF05xgsrOAAlYLgHpwebi4eVn39gbg%20A0-vHgHOFaNPDERCORrcG5-AEAryNACi4GAfGodEa-weXhowHSUA6vVQNgADApVvtNkdSM0AIwAVl2cAph22AE5iWdAnAAPTc1YsdzfPy-YKE2w0sloAbU%20ncdntHl8lYAIlB4OV3BWAq%203mFwFO525ACo4Gr%20W4dT99a93nqhZ9zo4nXAjdzgsEgA)

```js
export type StartsWith<S extends string, SearchString extends string> = S extends `${SearchString}${infer T}` ? true : false;
export type IsNegative<N extends number> = StartsWith<`${N}`, '-'>;

export type Sub<A extends number, B extends number> = [IsNegative<A>, IsNegative<B>] extends infer R
    ?  R extends  [false, false]
        ? ['Why?', R]
        : 'Expected'
    : never;

type T0 = [IsNegative<-15>, IsNegative<90>]; // [true, false]
type T1 = Sub<-15, 90>; // ["Why?", [true, false]] /* Why [true, false] extends [false, false] ??? */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason is that `startsWith` is not implemented correctly.
The correct way to write it is this:

```
export type StartsWith<S extends string, SearchString extends string> =
    string extends S ? boolean :
    S extends `${SearchString}${string}` ? true :
    false;
```

detail see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51090

----------------- The original answer ---------

```js
export type Sub<A extends number, B extends number> = IsNegative<A> extends infer IsNA
    ? IsNegative<B> extends infer IsNB
        ? [IsNA, IsNB] extends infer R
            ? R extends [false, false]
                ? ['UnExpected, Why?', R]
                : 'Expected'
            : never
        : never
    : never;
```

work well

It seems like you can't compute too many things at once, caching the results in two steps avoids this problem.(I'm used to caching the results of some types of evaluations using `Something infer Cache ? ... : never`)

That's a solution I can live with for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that TypeScript is lazily evaluating `IsNegative`, or it isn't evaluating it completely...? If we expand `IsNegative` to its full form:

```
type Sub<A extends number, B extends number> = [`${A}` extends `${"-"}${infer T}` ? true : false, `${B}` extends `${"-"}${infer T}` ? true : false] extends infer R
```

Then [you will get "Expected"](https://tsplay.dev/WJX9gN).

Also, if you change the definition of `IsNegative` to this:

```
type IsNegative<N extends number> = `${N}` extends `-${number}` ? true : false;
```

it [will also work](https://tsplay.dev/wj15vW).

So my takeaway is that TypeScript is being lazy, and "summarizes" `IsNegative` to `true | false` (basically, `boolean`), and then when needed, expands and evaluates the type...? At least, that's what I imagine what TypeScript is doing.

Comment: yes, but`[boolean, boolean] extends [false, false]` is always `false`, It should never go into the first branch： `? ['Why?', R]`.

Comment: Is the result of lazy computation `never`? It doesn't feel right from a design point of view